On Image Drag and Zoom not getting correct offset
Image is draging and zooming within Background as shown in image.
Zoom and pan is working fine
What Issue I am facing?
When drag or zoom view and reach to Start offset then start offset is showing as negative offset, Offset(0,0) is showing at any random coordinate of background view.
Following is my screen design

I try following code
                Image(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .height(250.nonScaledDp)
                        .offset {
                            IntOffset(
                                userImageOffset.x.toInt(),
                                userImageOffset.y.toInt()
                            )
                        }
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectTransformGestures { _, pan, zoom, _ ->
                                userImageScale = (userImageScale * zoom).coerceIn(
                                    0.5f,
                                    5f
                                )
                                userImageOffset = ParcelableOffset(
                                    userImageOffset.x + pan.x * userImageScale,
                                    userImageOffset.y + pan.y * userImageScale
                                )
                            }
                        }
                        .graphicsLayer {
                            scaleX = userImageScale
                            scaleY = userImageScale
                        },
                    painter = painter,
                    contentDescription = "",
                    contentScale = ContentScale.FillHeight
                )

Expected Result: Start offset should be 0,0
